# Can I edit source insight bookmark database

Tags: source-insight

I have a list for C source code position, which need to be add bookmark in the source insight project.
I want edit bookmark database directly.
For example the list is as following:

```
line 5406 of    file.c
line 5594 of    file.c
line 3761 of    file.c
```

Can i edit some file in source insight project, then make bookmark effectively.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a text file with your bookmarks, and then go to "Custom Commands".   For the `Run` box, add a command that echos your file (something like `type bookmarks.txt`).   Then select `Parse Links in Output`, update your pattern.   Once this is done, assign a key to it, and then press that key to generate your bookmarks.

---

*EDIT*

For more detailed walk through:

Go to `Tools`->`Custom Commands...`   Click on `Add...` button -- type in a name (say "add bookmarks").    Then in the `Run` dialog box, do `type filename.txt`.   Then select `Capture Output` checkbox, along with `Parse Links in Output`.   Select `Line then File`, and for pattern, do `line ([0-9]+) of ([A-Za-z0-9_\/.]+)`  Finally for Regular Expression Syntax, make sure you have `Perl Compatible` selected.

Comment: It is complex for understanding. Is there any demo on internet?